# Sequence to Sequence LSTM

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am training a stacked LSTM that takes as input a sequence `[1,...,n]` and outputs a sequence `[1,...,m]`, for `m<n`, to predict stock prices.

Upon training the model with multiple architecture nuances, I am getting the same result: the `yhat` sequences all have the same pattern.

What might be causing this?

*All input columns are z-scored

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably because there is no benefit is trying more nuanced architectures anyway. Stock prices are usually incredibly noisy data, neural networks excel when you have data with a complex structure yet not noisy (*e.g.* images, text, speech). Stock prices are the opposite, simple structure a lot of noise.

I would advise trying to model your data with something more simple, such as ARIMA or exponential smoothing.